# Heroku App crashes when trying to make a request to the API or just crashes after a few minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I have an express app that uses MongoDB, and I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku.

After deployment, it seems to work, but after a few minutes, it crashes. Before it crashes if I try to make a request to the API I get the following error.

```
"message": "Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms",
```

When it does crash, these are the message that i get from heroku cli

[image]

These are the main files

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import connectDb from './config/db.js'
import router from './routes/userRoutes.js'
import { errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js'
import cors from 'cors'

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

connectDb()

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use('/api/user', router)

app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on ${port}`))
```

db.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectDb = async () => {
    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.URL)
        console.log(`MonngoDb Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

export default connectDb
```

Procfile

```
web: node backend/server.js
```

The App works fine on my local machine but just crashes when deployed.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed:** Just needed to whitelist Heroku on network access